# Protección de código css y js en Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, css, laravel

Tengo una duda con respecto al código css y js en laravel, supongamos que tengo una aplicación web y contiene un panel de administración al cual se necesita login para usarlo osea esta protegido, pero ese panel de administración usa código css y js que están almacenados en la carpeta public de laravel entonces ¿Existe algún problema de seguridad? en caso de que exista ¿Cual es la mejor manera de manejar este tipos de archivos (css y js) para hacer la aplicación mas segura?

Muchas gracias de antemano y disculpen la ignorancia

Comment: No veo por donde el CSS pueda tener información sensible. Sólo preocúpate de que no haya información sensible (api keys) en el js.

Comment: Efectivamente como dice @amenadiel mientras no haya información sensible no hay problema. Preocupare que su  controlador  este validado correctamente y no alteren tu aplicación

Comment: Se me olvidó mencionar: la app de front debiera ser stateless. Pasas por una autenticación, el JS sólo hace de puente contra el backend y obtienes de éste un token que se guarda en el browser, o bien fijas una sesión (aunque esto está quedando obsoleto y te obliga a trabajar en forma monolítica). Los request son genéricos. La ruta se llama como la entidad, el verbo REST dicta la acción, no hay IDs en duro. El que baje tu JS tendrá en sus manos un CRUD genérico más una pincelada de la lógica de negocios. Con eso no tiene ni para empezar a imaginar cómo vulnerar tu app.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, tomare todo los concejos en cuenta.